# undefined 'touched' in angular2

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular

I am trying to validate my form but getting the error undefined touched, think i did something wrong with the import filed,can some one please suggest me some help.

My Template,

```
<h3 class = "head">MY PROFILE</h3>

<form   [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">     
      <label class="formHeading">firstname</label>
      <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control"  [formControl]="form.controls['firstname']" >  
    </div>
    <div *ngIf ="firstname.touched">
      <div *ngIf ="!firstname.valid" class = "alert alert-danger">
        <strong>First name is required</strong>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My Component,

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import {Control,ControlGroup} from '@angular/common';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES,FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators,    REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';

Component({
  templateUrl: './components/profile/profile.html',
  directives:   [CORE_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,FORM_DIRECTIVES,REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class Profile {
  http: Http;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fbld: FormBuilder,http: Http,public router: Router) {
    this.http = http;
    this.form = fbld .group({
      firstname: ['', Validators.required],
      lastname: ['', Validators.required],
      profilename :['', Validators.required],
      image : [''],
      phone : ['']
    });
  }

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form);
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    this.http.post('http://localhost/angular/index.php/profile/addprofile', JSON.stringify(form),{headers:headers});

    subscribe(response => {
      if(response.json().error_code === 0) {
        alert('added successfully');
        this.router.navigate(['/demo/professional']);
      } else {
        alert('fail');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I am trying to validate my form but getting the error undefined touched, think I did something wrong with the import files. Can someone please suggest me some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the control in the form. Try to use:

```
form.controls['firstname'].touched
```

and:

```
form.controls['firstname'].valid
```

Comment: but nw i am getting the error Cannot find control '''

Comment: See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/uiYZkEWMyXWOkglHZu6N. It's working fine.

Comment: can u post me some best resources reguarding forms

Comment: I use ng-book 2. La guida sui form è qui: http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/ Greetings